# How to execute stored procedure in EF7?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I need to quickly execute stored procedure which updates table with data from different data source in SQL Server. Is it possible to do it with EF7, I have tried FromSql, but this seems to only works with the mapped entities.

It doesn't need to return anything, just execute.

Is there any other method than using SQLConnection, or SQL job running every 10 minutes on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [DbContext.Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.database(v=vs.113).aspx) and [ExecuteSqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(System.String,System.Object[])) to execute your stored procedure.

```
   _db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC mySp");
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I've been looking for!